# What would an attacker need to know about the DNS request (itself) to successfully poison a DNS cache?

Tags: dns, dns-spoofing

According to a thread I recently read, in general, for one method of DNS poisoning, an attacker only needs to know the victim's DNS server (see this thread: [DNS cache poisoning](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25578/dns-cache-poisoning)). [I'm assuming the "DNS server" referred to here is the name server ("NS" Resource Record (RR))].

This was the answer provided for the question: "What are the things the attacker needs to know from the victim to perform DNS cache poisoning?"

However, what if the following question were posed: "What would an attacker need to know about the DNS request (itself) to successfully poison a DNS cache?"

My first thought is the only information an attacker would need to know about the DNS request/query would be the address record ("A" RR).

Perhaps my issue is with a bad question/answer in the referenced thread; however, in the interest of clearing up my confusion, are there other DNS record types of the targeted site needed, in general, to conduct a successful DNS cache poisoning?

Comment: The post you cite does not refer to the NS record (authoritive DNS for a domain) but to the DNS server used by the client. And which records are interesting depends on the attack. But apart from A the major interesting things to spoof are AAAA (IPv6) and MX (defines server which receives mail for domain) and maybe CNAME (alias).